# Web Scraping Yahoo Finance attempt not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance, stock, yahoo-finance

Thanks in advance for those who take thee time to read my issue!

I am trying to scrape some information off yahoo finance and have ran into some problems when I am running the program.

The Problem that I am running into is that in my last line when I am trying to write my values into the csv file, this error message keeps popping up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...", line 79, in 
csv_writer.writerow([j.name(), j.price(), j.pricetarget()])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Basically it is this last line ( csv_writer.writerow([j.name(), j.price(), j.pricetarget(), j.findpg()]) that is running into the problem.

I am unsure whether it is that the particular values does not exist on the website. Why does my object appear as a string and hence render the code unable to call the functions of the objects? hmmm

Background info: stock tickers.txt is a file that I am extracting my stock ticker names in order to parse and find the respective pages and information on yahoo finance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

csv_file = open('pricetarget.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Stock Ticker', 'Price', 'Price Target', 'Potential Gain'])

class ptfinder:
    def __init__(self, pturl, findpricetargettag, findpricetargetclass, priceurl, findpricetag, findpriceclass, nameurl, findnametag, findnameclass):
        self.pturl = pturl
        self.priceurl = priceurl
        self.findpricetag = findpricetag
        self.findpriceclass = findpriceclass
        self.nameurl = nameurl
        self.findnametag = findnametag
        self.findnameclass = findnameclass
        self.findpricetargettag = findpricetargettag
        self.findpricetargetclass = findpricetargetclass


    def name(self):
        self.source = requests.get(self.nameurl).text
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.source, 'lxml')
        self.name = self.soup.find(self.findnametag, class_=self.findnameclass).text
        return self.name

    def price(self):
        self.source = requests.get(self.priceurl).text
        self.soup1 = BeautifulSoup(self.source, 'lxml')
        try:
            self.price = self.soup1.find(self.findpricetag, class_=self.findpriceclass).text
            return self.price
        except:
            print('h')
            return 'No Price Provided'

    def pricetarget(self):
        self.source = requests.get(self.pturl).text
        self.soup2 = BeautifulSoup(self.source, 'lxml')
        try:
            self.pricetarget = self.soup2.find(self.findpricetargettag, class_=self.findpricetargetclass).text
            return self.pricetarget
        except:
            return 'No Price Target Provided'


    def findpg(self):
        self.pg = str(((self.pricetarget() - self.price())/self.price())*100) + '%'
        return self.pg



stocksymbols = []
stockname = []
pt = []
textfile = open("/Users/ryanong/PycharmProjects/investing/stockksymbols.txt", 'r')
for line in textfile:
    shares = list(line.split(','))
    stocksymbols.append(shares[0])
    stockname.append(shares[1])

for i in range(50):
    checkstock = str(stocksymbols[i])
    nameurl = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + checkstock + '/analysis?p=' + checkstock
    priceurl = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + checkstock + '/analysis?p=' + checkstock
    pturl = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + checkstock + '/analysis?p=' + checkstock
    s = ptfinder(
        pturl, 'span', "Trsdu(0.3s)",
        priceurl, 'span', 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)',
        nameurl, 'h1', 'D(ib) Fz(18px)')
    pt.append(s)


for j in pt:
    csv_writer.writerow([j.name(), j.price(), j.pricetarget(), j.findpg()])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: `j` is the same is known as a string at line 79. This is where you error comes from. To make sure that's the issue, you should add this line before the `csv_writer.writenow(...)`: `print(typeof(j))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing method names and properties, for example:

```py
    def pricetarget(self):                               # <--- method name is "pricetarget"
        self.source = requests.get(self.pturl).text
        self.soup2 = BeautifulSoup(self.source, "lxml")
        try:
            self.pricetarget = self.soup2.find(          # <--- here you're rewriting the method with string
                self.findpricetargettag, class_=self.findpricetargetclass
            ).text
            return self.pricetarget
        except:
            return "No Price Target Provided"
```

The solution is to rename `def pricetarget(self)` or the variable `self.pricetarget`.

Also, make sure that `pricetarget()` and `price()` return `float` and not string, because you will get error inside the `findpg()` function

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not realise that I was using my methods within the methods as variables. Thank you for spotting my mistake.